# Using avx2 to retrieve and interleave elements from two vectors

Tags: assembly, intel, intrinsics, avx, avx2

Given two single-precision floats vectors a and b in avx2 : 

a : [0; 1; 2 ; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7]

b : [8; 9; 10 ; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15]

I would like to take one element out of two in both vectors and interleave them in the output. Ideally, a control selector would help me to specify which element I choose in both vector (the even or odd ones, let's say). So for a and b the possible outputs would be :

v0: [0; 8; 2; 10; 4; 12; 6; 14]

v1: [1; 8; 3; 10; 5; 12; 7; 14]

v2: [0; 9; 2; 11; 4; 13; 6; 15]

v3: [1; 9; 3; 11; 5; 13; 7; 15]

Blend_ps can do the job for v2 if I'm not mistaken, I need the other ones. Ideally it would take one instruction (I'm confident I can find a solution otherwise, for example by permuting one of the input and then doing a blend). I'm asking because this looks like a quite regular kind of operation, and it does not seem too far-fetched that something like this could be hard-coded in the ISA, but I couldn't find anything completely relevant until now. For example it doesn't do cross-lane accesses.

Unpack_hi and unpack_lo are actually very close, but they interleave at a bigger granularity -  what you get is something of this shape : 
[A; A; B; B; A; A; B; B]

Where A (B) denotes an element coming from vector a (b)

Is there such an instruction ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: clang also just finds a single-instruction implementation for `v2`: https://godbolt.org/z/uVm5FH Are you sure you need the other variants, or do you have options like `[a0, a2, b0, b2; a4, a6, b4, b6]` (that would be a `shufps`)?

Comment: None of your data crosses lane boundaries so there's hope for `vshufps` if the pattern in the high and low lanes are the same.  Or you might need a temporary shuffle result and then blendps.  This is just from a quick look.  And BTW, no `_mm256_unpacklo_ps` alternates floats between the two vectors.  It's `A B A B` but with no gaps.  `A A B B` would be what you'd get from using unpack..._pd on float data.

Comment: First, thanks for the answers. If I read correctly this doc: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4754,4754,5199&text=vshufps I think shuffle_ps does not fit my need - it does a AABBAABB pattern (as far as I understand, what unpack_{lo,hi} implements is actually a specific case of shuffle_ps. With my notation, unpack_lo would return [0;1;8;9;4;5;12;13] and unpack_hi [2;3;10;11;6;7;14;15].

Comment: Shuffle is more general in the sens that it allows me to select : two (arbitrary) elements from the first lane of a, then two elements from the first lane of b, then two elements of the second lane of a, etc. I need to get one element of a, then one element of b, etc.

Comment: Actually I think I can easily do it in two instructions at worse : First a shift and then a blend. I would fallback on that if needed but for now I wanted to be sure that there is no immediate way.

Comment: As chtz says, you could build `v2` with just a blend.  Then maybe `shufps` between the blend result and one of the original vectors?  Or yes, AVX2 integer shift (like `vpsrlq ymm, 32`) then FP blendps is a good idea.  Shuffle throughput can easily be a bottleneck; before IceLake Intel CPUs only have 1/clock shuffle throughput.

Comment: Two instruction interleave should never be a problem (if nothing else works, some form of `shufps tmp, a, b, imm; shufps tmp, tmp, tmp, imm` should do). Shift+blend is likely better, if you bottleneck on shuffling (as Peter says). I'd still think about whether (in the bigger context) you actually need the output to be interleaved exactly as you described (or perhaps have an option to have the input in a different form).

Comment: Well, if you want some context, I am trying to specify a kind of DSL that allows me to represent more or less the shuffling operations I can do with vectors instructions. The goal is to then explore the space of possible transformation to find some optimized layout transformation. The language does not have to match exactly what is actually possible on a cpu but should be as close as possible, and a good solution (for example for a matrix-transpostion) in my search space would ideally have an efficient concrete implementation. Hope it helps a bit

Comment: Oh, to conclude, this kind of operation (selecting some parts of a vector, but with some regularities, like one out of two, or two out of four) is made first-class (as I thought it would be easy to implement). The DSL should as much as possible be architecture-agnostic.